# How to implement .tex-files without using the whole path?

Tags: input

**See Screenshot:**
In my main.tex document i call/implement many .tex-Files. 
Is it possible to use this red command in my main.tex document? Instead of the dark red commands?

[image]

Comment: crosspost http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/19882/einbindung-von-tex-files-ohne-angabe-des-ganzen-pfads

Comment: any suggests? thx

Comment: It is my understanding that input files are unable to detect where they are located. So, an input file cannot call another inpt file by relative path. Instead (as in the dark red) the paths are always relative to the main TeX document. This is because each input file is not interpreted by itself. Instead, its text is first brought into the main document, just as if its text were directly written in the main document. Only then, is it evaluated. So, the fact that it began as an input file, no longer matters. Summary: Your request cannot be done.

Comment: Use package [`import`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/import) as shown in http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/19882/einbindung-von-tex-files-ohne-angabe-des-ganzen-pfads/19894